# How to create a task on Windows to open a webpage and then close it?

Tags: php, scheduled-tasks, windows-server

I have a script written in PHP. my PHP server is running on a Windows Server.

How can I schedule a task that will open a web link "URL" and after the page finish executing close the browser.

Thanks

Comment: What is it that you're ultimately trying to achieve?

Comment: How are you defining "page finish executing"?

Comment: cron on windows is done with windows scheduler, you don't need to use the browser

Comment: 1) You don't need a web browser for this, you simply need anything that can fetch a webpage's content such as wget or cURL. 2) If you need the script to run on a regular basis, consider running the script from the command line *on the server* instead of calling it remotely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, you use the Windows Task Scheduler which allows similar functionality to CRON but also a lot more (startup/down, events, etc.)

You can call Internet Explorer from a command  with the url as a parameter:

```
iexplore.exe "http://etc.etc.etc"
```

You may need to explicitly add the path to iexplore.exe
Of course, as you say, you would then need to kill the browser process afterwards.

Better would be to add a simpler command to a folder on your path such as CURL for Windows or [WGET for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm). Direct the output of the command to null, the command will exit with a testable return code should you need to further check whether it worked.

A third option would be to use PowerShell though I think that would be overkill in this case. I'd use it if I needed to test the return code for logging or to execute some other task on failure (e.g. write an error to the Windows Event Log and have a second task set up to run when that event occurs).

A 4th option would be to call PHP as this is supported if you have PHP installed on the server. Again though, the overheads of startup wouldn't make this worthwhile.

Personally, I would use WGET.

Comment: Thank you. I used #4 as it was the perfect option. I created a bad file with @ECHO OFF  c:\path\to\php\php.exe -f c:\path\to\myphpscript\filetoexecute.php  then I scheduled a task to execute this .bat file.

Answer (score 2):

The answer of Julian Knight has some drawbacks:

It will leave IEInstances open, which you have to kill manually... While searching for a "One-Liner" to achieve the same goal, I found powershell to be very helpful:

Task-Scheduler, target: `Powershell.exe`, use arguments:

```
-Command "(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('http://myhost/cron/cron.php')"
```

This will download the whole content (render the whole DOM), and then quit the powershell-instance.

Comment: can we call two webpages by single task scheduler? like two downloadstring / two -command option or any other way ? Basically I need to call 3 webpages and i don't want to create 3 diff schedulers for it.